# Android device only visible in recovery mode

Tags: android, adb

If I run `adb devices` while my Nexus 4 is in recovery mode, I see the appropiate entry.

```
List of devices attached 
0174395ce35136bd    recovery
```

However if I reboot into the bootloader, no entry shows up. What might cause this? I need to be able to operate on the device in this state to re-flash the stock Android rom.

`lsusb` (I am running linux) shows the same corresponding entry in both cases

```
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 18d1:4ee0 Google Inc.
```

And I ran `adb start-server` as root, so it should not be a permissions issue.

Comment: Does a different USB VID & PID perhaps appear in that mode, which (depending on host operating system) ADB might either not know about, or not have been granted permission to access?  You should probably connect the device in that mode and check device manager / lsusb / whatever the system status thing is on a Mac.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I just updated the question. The output of lsusb is identical in both cases.

Comment: Wait a minute, aren't adb and fastboot distinct tools?  Is adb even supposed to see a fastboot mode device?  Wouldn't the appropriate list devices command be `fastboot devices` ?

Comment: You're right; it shows up under `fastboot devices`. I didn't realize that this distinction existed.

Comment: If you're interested in posting that as the answer I'll accept. In any case thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adb` and `fastboot` are distinct tools / protocols, so `adb devices` is probably not supposed to see fastboot-mode targets.

The appropriate device list command would be

`fastboot devices`

Answer (score 0):

also in recovery mode you can access adb functions if you update the driver on the os side typically window: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/howto-use-adb-in-recovery.1957423/